# Is there a Python library for a derivative of dictionary with callback functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there a Python library which has a stable data structure for a derivative of dictionary (or a derivative of  `collections.MutableMapping`) with callback functions? The 'callback functions', I mean, are called when the dictionary sets or gets items. The following is what I implemented for this purpose.

```
from collections import MutableMapping

class TriggerDict(MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._dict = dict()
        self._triggers_set = dict()
        self._triggers_get = dict()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.set(key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._dict[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._dict)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._dict)

    def keys(self):
        return self._dict.keys()

    def values(self):
        return self._dict.values()

    def set_trigger(self, key, func, when='set'):
        if when == 'set':
            self._triggers_set[key] = func
        elif when == 'get':
            self._triggers_get[key] = func
        else:
            ValueError("You should choose 'set' or 'get' "
                       "for the timing of trigger, not '%s.'"%(when))

    def set(self, key, value, trigger=True):
        if key not in self._triggers_set:
            self._dict[key] = value
            return

        if trigger:
            func = self._triggers_set[key]
            self._dict[key] = func(key, value)
        else:
            self._dict[key] = value

    def get(self, key, default=None, trigger=True):
        if key not in self._triggers_get:
            return self._dict.get(key, default)

        if trigger:
            func = self._triggers_get[key]
            value = self._dict.get(key, default)
            return func(key, value)
        else:
            return self._dict.get(key, default)


def say_hello(key, value):
    print("Hello! %s"%(value))
    return value

def say_thanks(key, value):
    print("Thanks! %s"%(value))
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':

    td = TriggerDict()
    td.set_trigger('GREETING', say_hello, when='set')
    td.set_trigger('GREETING', say_thanks, when='get')

    td['GREETING'] = 'Daewon'
    td['GREETING']

def say_thanks(key, value):
    print("Thanks! %s"%(value))
    return value

td = TriggerDict()
td.set_trigger('GREETING', say_hello, when='set')
td.set_trigger('GREETING', say_thanks, when='get')

td['GREETING'] = 'Daewon'
td['GREETING']
```

I refactored the above code according to VPfB's comment as follows.

```
class TriggerDict(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._triggers_set = dict()
        self._triggers_get = dict()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.set(key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.get(key)

    def set_trigger(self, key, func, when='set'):
        if when == 'set':
            self._triggers_set[key] = func
        elif when == 'get':
            self._triggers_get[key] = func
        else:
            ValueError("You should choose 'set' or 'get' "
                       "for the timing of trigger, not '%s.'"%(when))

    def set(self, key, value, trigger=True):
        if key not in self._triggers_set:
            self.data[key] = value
            return

        if trigger:
            func = self._triggers_set[key]
            self.data[key] = func(key, value)
        else:
            self.data[key] = value

    def get(self, key, default=None, trigger=True):
        if key not in self._triggers_get:
            return self.data.get(key, default)

        if trigger:
            func = self._triggers_get[key]
            value = self.data.get(key, default)
            return func(key, value)
        else:
            return self.data.get(key, default)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?  Are you getting errors?  Or are you just looking for an off-site resource which has already done this?  In the latter case, that is unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow's QA...

Comment: @mgilson I am satisfied with my code I've posted here. But I want to use more 'standard' or 'stable' one if it exists in a form of package or library.

Comment: Can't answer the main question. But regarding your code: did you consider to subclass `UserDict`? The basic dict stuff is implemented there already.

Comment: @VPfB Thanks for your comment. It's better.